# Data not being passed from parent component to child component in React.js

Tags: reactjs

Working on a react page where I fetch data from an api call and then show the data.  I have a button that brings up a pop up that allows the user to edit the data that was displayed.

My problem is that the parent page will display the data.  How ever, the data is not being passed to the child component to be edited.

Parent Code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Login from '../Components/Login/Login';
import useToken from './App/useToken';
import EditUser from './User/EditUser';

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Profile = () => {
  const {token, settoken }= useToken();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [inputEmailValue, setInputEmailValue] = useState('');
  const [inputFirstValue, setInputFirstValue] = useState('');
  const [inputLastValue, setInputLastValue] = useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [showEditUser, setShowEditUser] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  if(!token) {
    return<Login settoken={settoken} />
  }

  const getData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/users/byemail/${token.email}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token.token}`
      }
    });

    const temp = await response.json();
    setInputEmailValue(temp.email);
    setInputFirstValue(temp.firstName);
    setInputLastValue(temp.lastName);
  
    setData(temp);
  }

  const handleLogOut = () => {
    settoken(null);
    navigate('/');
  }

  const handleClosePopup = () => {
    setShowEditUser(false);
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <h1>User Profile</h1>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td>{inputEmailValue}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>{inputFirstValue}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>{inputLastValue}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
            
      <button className="button" id="editBtn" onClick={() => setShowEditUser(true)}>Edit User Info</button>
      <EditUser data={data} onClose={handleClosePopup} showEditUser={showEditUser}/>      
      <button className="button" id="logoutBtn" onClick={() => handleLogOut()}>Logout</button>
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default Profile
```

Child Code

```
mport React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import TextField from '../App/UIComponents/textField.jsx';
import useToken from '../App/useToken';
import Login from '../Login/Login.jsx';

export default function EditUser(props) {
    const {token, settoken }= useToken();
    const [inputEmailValue, setInputEmailValue] = useState(`${props.data}`);
    const [inputFirstValue, setInputFirstValue] = useState(props.email);
    const [inputLastValue, setInputLastValue] = useState(props.email);
    
    if(!token) {
        return<Login settoken={settoken} />
    }

    if (!props.showEditUser) {
        return null;
    }

    const handleInputEmailChange = (event) => {
        setInputEmailValue(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleInputFirstChange = (event) => {
        setInputFirstValue(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleInputLastChange = (event) => {
        setInputLastValue(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleOnClose = () => {
        props.onClose();
    };

    const handleOnClick = () => {
        //Code to handle edit of data
    };

    return (
        <div className='popup' name='edituser'>
            <div className='popup-content'>
                <div className='model-header'>
                    <h2 className='model-title'>Edit User</h2>
                </div>
                <div className='model-body'>
                    <TextField title="First Name"
                            placeHolder={inputEmailValue}
                            name="firstName"
                            inputValue={inputEmailValue}
                            handleInputChange={handleInputEmailChange} 
                            validate={false}
                            error="" />
                    <TextField title="First Name"
                        placeHolder={inputFirstValue}
                        name="firstName"
                        inputValue={inputFirstValue}
                        handleInputChange={handleInputFirstChange} 
                        validate={false}
                        error="" />
                    <TextField title="Last Name"
                        placeHolder={inputLastValue}
                        name="lastName"
                        inputValue={inputLastValue}
                        handleInputChange={handleInputLastChange} 
                        validate={false}
                        error="" />
                </div>
                <div className='model-footer'>
                    <button onClick={handleOnClick} className="button" name='editBtn'>Edit User</button>
                    <button className='button' onClick={handleOnClose}>Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  
}
```

I have tried to pass the info from the parent to child several ways.  I am expecting the data shown in the parent to also be shown in the child component.  How ever, the parent shows the data correctly, but the child doesn't show the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the data from the API as a JSON object, breaking the values into individual state variables (email, first, last), are displaying those individual values in the Parent, but then trying to pass the JSON `data` to the child for editing in the child's own state variables.

This is a pretty confusing setup.

One option would be to pass both the variables and the set-state-functions" of (email, first, last) from the Parent to the Child, and let the Child's input fields display the (email, first, last) state variable values and the input fields' onChange would pass the new input value to the (email, first, last) set-state-functions.

```js
<EditUser
  onClose={handleClosePopup}
  showEditUser={showEditUser}
  email={inputEmailValue}
  setEmail={setInputEmailValue}
  firstName={inputFirstValue}
  setFirstName={setInputFirstValue}
  lastName={inputLastValue}
  setLastName={setInputLastValue}
/>
```

and then in the Child:

```js
export default function EditUser(props) {
  // ...
  <TextField title="Email Address"
    placeHolder="Email Address"
    name="emailAddress"
    inputValue={props.email}
    handleInputChange={(evt) => props.setEmail(evt.target.value)} 
    validate={false}
    error="" />

  <TextField title="First Name"
    placeHolder="First Name"
    name="firstName"
    inputValue={props.firstName}
    handleInputChange={(evt) => props.setFirstName(evt.target.value)} 
    validate={false}
    error="" />

  <TextField title="Last Name"
    placeHolder="Last Name"
    name="firstName"
    inputValue={props.lastName}
    handleInputChange={(evt) => props.setLastName(evt.target.value)} 
    validate={false}
    error="" />
 // ...
```

Also, recognize that React is a "tree of components" that start with the top-most component (typically named `<App>`)...and it renders components all the way down.

If there is something you want to do in a bunch of places such as check whether the user is logged in, you can put that check at a component high up in the tree and then nothing lower down would need to do that same check over and over and over....so the code:

```js
const {token, settoken }= useToken();
...    
if(!token) {
  return <Login settoken={settoken} />
}
```

could be done once ... say in the parent of `<Profile>` or even higher in the tree...and then you don't have to put that code in all these lower components.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried this and it fixed the issue I was facing.